# SSIS Variable Expression - Convert to String

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have created a String variable in SSIS and address expression in the Expression builder as follows,
Evaluate Expression works fine. But When run my package it's giving me an error. I know it's a casting problem. I couldn't fix it. Can someone help me?

```
"dbo.zkt_attendance_Date ' (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE() ) ',' (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART(MM, GETDATE() )','+ (DT_STR, 2, 1252) @[User::Dates] +'"
```

[image: Expression Builder]

[image: Vaiable]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is

```
"dbo.zkt_attendance_Date ' (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE() ) ',' (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART(MM, GETDATE() )','+ (DT_STR, 2, 1252) @[User::Dates] +'"
```

That literally evaluates to

```
"dbo.zkt_attendance_Date ' (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE() ) ',' (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART(MM, GETDATE() )','+ (DT_STR, 2, 1252) @[User::Dates] +'"
```

The double quote is the begining/ending for a string literal in the expression language. Instead, you're looking to mix and match what's in double quotes with the concatenation `+` operators.

Something like this (returns added for readability)

```
"dbo.zkt_attendance_Date '" 
+ (DT_STR, 4, 1252) DATEPART("YYYY", GETDATE() ) 
+ "','"
+ (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("MM", GETDATE() )
+ "', '"
+ (DT_STR, 2, 1252) @[User::Dates] 
+ "'"
```

Also, `(DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("YYYY", GETDATE() )` is going to fail as you have string truncation

The evaluated value for that is, assuming I have 03 in the @[User::Dates] variable

```
dbo.zkt_attendance_Date '2020','5', '03'
```